# How do I show a marker in Maps launched by geo URI Intent?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-maps

I have a application where I want to show different locations (one at the time, picked by user input) by launching Google Maps with their specific geo coordinates.

I'm currently using this (with real lat. and long. values of course):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<lat>,<long>?z=17"));
startActivity(intent);
```

It's quite exactly what I want, except that it doesn't show any indicator or marker for the specified point. It only centers at it's location.

Is there some way to get the marker or something else included without using a MapView?

Comment: the label has stopped showing in most recent maps update .. what to do?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<lat>,<long>?q=<lat>,<long>(Label+Name)"));
startActivity(intent);
```

You can omit (Label+Name) if you don't want a label, and it will choose one randomly based on the nearest street or other thing it thinks relevant.

Comment: After implementing this URI i have problems setting the zoom. It seems to be obsolete now

Comment: @mmm...: You'll need to change the ?z to an &z. You can only have one ? in a uri. BAD: geo:N,M?z=10?q=N,M(Place) GOOD: geo:N,M?z=10&q=N,M(Place)

Comment: No zoom still doesn't work (but the label thing does). Also if maps can't find anything relevant (even though we supply it with the label) it will show a toast error. This solution works but only semi optimal.

Comment: That was special, Droider. Instead of <long> and <lat> you enter the longitudinal and latitudinal value you require.

Comment: Zoom is ignored because this is a simple query rather than a geointent. What happens here is actually a plain query that is sent to Google, and then the server responds with a "search result" corresponding to it. You can try searching for  <lat>,<long>(Label+Name) on maps.google.com and get the same result

Comment: Using this(or any of the other methods here which involve a labeled query) completely ignores the geopoint in the `geo:` portion, lke robpvn pointed out. In some cases the query will fail using lat/long, and then you just get a "no results" toast instead of falling back to geopoint. Not very useful for any sort of GIS app.

Comment: This functionality was broken in new Google Maps 7.x, see too https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58507

Comment: There's official documentation on: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

Comment: this doesn't work any more .. the label does not show

Comment: how to do it with multiple of latlong andorid

Comment: this is working, Android12, Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:"+latitude+","+longitude+"?z="+zoom+"&q="+latitude+","+longitude);

Answer (score 51):

### There are many more options to launch a Google map using an intent...

```
   Double myLatitude = 44.433106;
   Double myLongitude = 26.103687;
   String labelLocation = "Jorgesys @ Bucharest";
```

#### 1)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<" + myLatitude  + ">,<" + myLongitude + ">?q=<" + myLatitude  + ">,<" + myLongitude + ">(" + labelLocation + ")"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

#### 2)

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ myLatitude  +"," + myLongitude +"("+ labelLocation + ")&iwloc=A&hl=es";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
    startActivity(intent);
```

#### 3)

```
   String urlAddress = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=500x500&location=" + myLatitude  + "," + myLongitude + "&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: looks like for 2) "&iwloc=A&hl=es" is not really needed

Comment: "iwloc" stands for info window location and "hl" for the language, if you don´t set this values, default values apply. =)

Comment: you miss `)` on second way.

Comment: Ups! second and third option! thanks I have fixed both! ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ @Baras

Answer (score 45):

The accepted answer is correct, except when your label has an ampersand (&) in it.

Looking at [A Uniform Resource Identifier for Geographic Locations ('geo' URI)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-mayrhofer-geo-uri-00#section-5.1):

Section 5.1 states:

> if the final URI is to include a 'query' component, add the
> component delimiter "?" to the end of the result, followed by the
> encoded query string.

Unfortunately for us, doing this will also escape the '=' which is not what we want.

We should do this:

```
String label = "Cinnamon & Toast";
String uriBegin = "geo:12,34";
String query = "12,34(" + label + ")";
String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This functionality was broken in new Google Maps 7.x, see too https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58507

Answer (score 6):

This string works well for me:

```
String geoUriString="geo:"+lat+","+lon+"?q=("+head+")@"+lat+","+lon;
Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(geoUriString);
Log.e(TAG, "String: "+geoUriString);
Intent mapCall  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);
startActivity(mapCall);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try appending (LocationMarkerName) to the geo: uri. For example, "geo:,?z=17(LocationMarkerName)"

In Google Maps on Android searching for 23.0980,30.6797 (NamedMarker), it seems to centre the map and position a marker with name NamedMarker at that position.

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed the following snippet from @Kenton Price still works on Android 4.4 (KitKat):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<lat>,<long>?q=<lat>,<long>(Label+Name)"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only used Overlays with the MapView for drawing markers on top of a map. If your view is showing your map, it might be possible to simply draw your marker at the centre of the screen, in the same way as you would draw any image on a View.

However, the marker wouldn't be linked to the actual map coordinates, but if it's just a static view, then this might do.