# Android google maps intent zooms too far

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am trying to fix a bug from QA team. When Android starts the intent to search for a specific address it zooms in too far(~200ft) Would like it set the distance further away around 1000ft Its like maps is ignoring the z param completely if I give it a query.

I have tried every way I can think of, even went thru google docs and tried this:

```
 Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?z=10&q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

But it still ignored the zoom level with address in there.

Here is my code now:

```
String geo = "geo:" +(mCampground.latitude + "," + mCampground.longitude);
String maplLabel =(mCampground.title);
String query  =Uri.encode(mCampground.address1 + "(" + maplLabel+")");
String uriString = geo + "?q=" + query + "&z=10";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startExternalActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Have you tried a value other than 10 to see if you get results you like better?

Comment: This may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053352/android-how-to-launch-google-map-intent-in-android-app-with-certain-location

Comment: yes I have tried many values even 3 which is world view

Comment: @Demonsoul I have tried this too and same problem.