# google maps intent zooming to location of device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I am trying to get google maps to zoom to the location of the device being used.

google maps is launched from inside my application via an intent the code is below.

```
button_bakery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Breakfast_bakery);
    button_bakery.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View views) {
                    Button b = button_bakery;
                    String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

                    // Search for restaurants nearby
                    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + buttonText);
                    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                    startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
            }
    );
```

however this loads the location as the last location set by the device when using this application. Is there a way to set it to zoom to the current location of the device before the search is completed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By following this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#uri_encoded_query_strings), you can use the `geo:` intent to display the zoom level that you want.

```
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
```

The `z` parameter sets the initial zoom level of the map. Accepted values range from 0 (the whole world) to 21 (individual buildings).

Here is a example code that use zoom level equal to 10(z=10) that will attemp to find restaurant at a city level.

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?z=10&q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053352/android-how-to-launch-google-map-intent-in-android-app-with-certain-location) for more information.