# Calling Maps intent with geolocation, is it possible to have a pushpin on it?

Tags: android, google-maps, pushpin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to show marker in Maps launched by geo uri Intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990110/how-to-show-marker-in-maps-launched-by-geo-uri-intent)

I have an intent to a Google Maps application with one geolocation I got from my database, is it possible for GM to put a pushpin in the location I'm sending with the URI?

```
final String uri = "geo:" + location.Latitude + "," + location.Longitude + "?z=12";
MyActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990110/how-to-show-marker-in-maps-launched-by-geo-uri-intent

Comment: Ok, I have started a closevote as duplicated with that link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify a name for the pin:

```
String uri = "geo:0,0?q="+ Lat + "," + Longitude + " (" + name+ ")";
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

This will work for one pin only.

Comment: "geo:" + location.Latitude + "," + location.Longitude + "?z=12"
                        + "&q=" + location.Latitude + "," + location.Longitude + "(Syncpoint)";

It needs the & to include both the query and the zoom.