# Display text on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am displaying a location on Google map by passing latitude longitude values.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + (" "+dblLatitude+", "+dblLongitude+" ")));

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.map_locate);
    }
```

Its working fine for me. But I also want to show text on above the located point. Any idea how to pass the text dynamically like I am passing lat, long values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a label on Google Maps application you have to add it in brackets after coordinates.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7405992/2183804

Answer (score 0):

You can put extra data into the intent object using e.g. [the putExtra(String,String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method on the intent object.

Comment: I know I can put the data to intent. But how to retrieve that data onto google map?

Answer (score 0):

As you firing an intent to turn on the native Google Maps Application. I don't think that what you are trying to achieve is possible. AFAIK all you can add to the desired location is an icon.

If you want to add to it more functionality you would have to develop your own map application.

**UPDATE:**

To develop you own map, you can take a look at this blog post I wrote on that matter:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

If you have questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @ Emil Adz : thanks for the info. i will try to develop my own map.